# Does the verb "to onset" exist?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

I just heard (for the first time)

> onset

being used as a verb in a scientific talk. According to ODE and Webster, there is no verb "onset". However, wikipedia does [mention](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/onset) it. Could the native speakers please weigh in?

Comment: I don't think I'd ever (in a formal situation) use "onset" as a verb.  (But I love to butcher the language in informal situations.)

Comment: In response to Macbeth's challenge, Macduff promptly and vigorously onlaid.

Comment: Just about *any* word can be "verbified". This question is nothing more than an invitation to discuss a general feature of English (and probably most if not all other languages).

Answer (score 1):

No, that wouldn't be proper since "onset" is itself a noun derived from a verbal phrase, "setting on". To say something like "The syndrome onsetted..." would be awkward since "onset" is a passive event; a better word would be "began" or "commenced".

Comment: The past tense of _set_ as a verb is _set_, not _setted_. And what do you mean _onset_ is a “passive event”? _Inset_ is also originally a noun formed in the exact same manner, but that works just fine as a verb (and the past tense is _inset_, not _*insetted_).

Answer (score 1):

How exactly was it used? There is indeed a verb *onset*, which means to attack something or someone, or figuratively to debate, argue or contest something.

It's pretty much obsolete these days though, and has been for the last few centuries, and one generally uses "set upon" instead.

Without context I would guess a modern use was a novel use, turning the noun *onset* to verb use, which is a common enough thing to do in English, especially in informal English, but it could be a retention as dialects and ideolects do sometimes make use of words and senses generally considered obsolete.

There are both a sense meaning "to oppress" and a sense meaning "to bestow or confer", but they're much more obsolete, being an Old English use that didn't survive into Middle English.

A comment adds further:

> It was used to describe the onset of magnetism in a material, or the onset of a signal at a critical temperature.

And makes it clear that this is indeed a case of turning the noun *onset* to verb use. It also shows it to be the sort of case where one would most often use a word in a different part than normal. English doesn't have a commonly used verb for this case, so to avoid ungainly repetition of a larger phrase ("induces the onset of" or such) people who are talking about particular things often create jargon to ease doing so, and verbing nouns (and indeed nouning verbs) is a common way to do so.

Comment: It was used to describe the onset of magnetism in a material, or the onset of a signal at a critical temperature.